# Can "plural subjects be single object"?

Tags: grammar

"Computers are often argued to be the most important invention of the last hundred years." Could anyone tell me whether this sentence is right? And why? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is perfectly correct. Here is another example:

> These flowers are a gift from an admirer

When we talk about the flowers themselves, we view them as plural. When we talk about those same flowers as a gift, we view them as singular.

In the same way, if we talk about a packet of biscuits, when we talk about the biscuits themselves, we  view them as plural, but when we think of them as a packet, the packet is singular.